# Org-ref mouseover timer

Tags: org-mode, org-ref, tooltip

Org-ref provides excellent bibliographic tools for authoring within org documents. However, one issue I've had is the mouseover timer for citation links appears to be set to zero seconds. That is, whenever the mouse pointer passes over a citation link, no matter how quickly, the link information is opened in a helm buffer at the bottom of the frame and persists until I click somewhere in the org buffer.

Is there a way to set this timer such that it only opens the additional helm buffer only when the mouse hovers over the citation for a specified duration, e.g. one second?

I could not find a mouseover timer setting in the org-ref documentation or customization. I'm not even sure if this is caused by org-ref, org, helm, or emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set for 0.5 sec. It is not customizable at the moment. But you can turn it off with the command rg-ref-cancel-link-messages I think.

Comment: You can also set org-ref-show-citation-on-enter to nil to turn off the messages.

Comment: The tooltip delay is 0.5 seconds. Previously, helm was opening a buffer on mouseover with no delay, but the problem does not seem to be repeatable, it may have been a session error. Many thanks.

Comment: Clarification: On mouseover only _references_ open instantly in a helm buffer. Citations behave as expected, on mouseover a tooltip appears after 0.5 seconds, no helm action.